# Azure notification hub dependencies not working

Tags: android, azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm following the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started) for Push Notification, but when I tried to implement the lib, its not working.

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.6@aar'
```

Thats the only error that I get :

```
Failed to resolve: com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following repository after the dependencies section.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @NathielPaulino I created a new android project with android studio. If I add the lib without the repositories, I will encounter the same error as yours. But after adding the repositories. It works well.

Comment: After adding the repositories, I click 'sync now' again, it works.